# ejabberd server not starting in windows

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mnesia

i have installed ejabberd 17.01 on windows 8.1 using binary installer but when i try to start the server( using desktop icon, start.cmd in bin dir and ejabberdctl start ) it takes me to the error page and nothing happens.

Checking the status( using ejabberdctl status ) shows:

```
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started  
ejabberd is not running in that node
```

here is my log file:

```
(ejabberd@localhost)1> 11:29:56.676 [error] Failed to open log file C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/logs/ejabberd.log with error permission denied  
11:29:56.676 [error] Failed to open log file c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/logs/error.log with error permission denied  
11:29:56.951 [info] Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:56.964 [info] Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:56.976 [info] Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:56.999 [info] Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:56.999 [info] Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.015 [info] Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.036 [info] Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.067 [info] Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.096 [info] Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.104 [info] Application p1_utils started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.111 [info] Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.113 [info] Application xmpp started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.137 [info] Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.152 [error] Failed to open crash log file c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/logs/crash.log with error: permission denied    
11:29:57.181 [info] Application elixir started on node ejabberd@localhost  
11:29:57.238 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.41.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {aborted,{"Cannot read schema","c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/mnesia/schema.DAT",{error,{file_error,"c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/mnesia/schema.DAT",eacces}}}} in application_master:init/4 line 134  
11:29:57.238 [info] Application ejabberd exited with reason: {aborted,{"Cannot read schema","c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/mnesia/schema.DAT",{error,{file_error,"c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/mnesia/schema.DAT",eacces}}}}
```

I think the problem is in mnesia database schema, any idea how to fix it?

I searched for the problem almost everywhere but nothing related to mnesia schema problem.

I uninstalled and reinstalled ejabbred for 3times but same problem.
Please help how to fix it. I am new to ejabbred.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `eacces` suggests that the user that ejabberd is running as doesn't have permissions to access `c:/ProgramData/ejabberd/database/mnesia/schema.DAT`. Could that be the case?

Comment: Change the permission for the ejabberd folder to Full Control. Right Click Properties > Security > Advanced > Change Permission